# log4net: Logging works only in the Mainclass

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I've got a Windows Service that creates an instance of a Class every x minutes by using System.Threads and Timers.The logging in the mainclass where the servicecall is made works, but the called classes can't log, i just do not get any output.

Thats my framework of the mainclass:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an Instance of the Log
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Test");

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the Instance of the Log
    /// </summary>
    internal static ILog log
    {
        get { return logger; }
    }
```

If i now call out of any other class the Service.log reference and try to write a log, e.g Service.log.Info("test"); nothing comes up.

If i try to create a new Instance of the log in the 2nd Class, by using

```
/// <summary>
/// Create an Instance of the Log
/// </summary>
private static readonly ILog logsomething = LogManager.GetLogger("Test");
```

I do not get any output either, it only works in the mainclass. i cant get it to work in any other threaded class. My configuration is based on RollingFileAppender.

Comment: Can you please post your configuration?

Answer (score 0):

May be log4net is erring out. Enable tracing and check the log for additional details.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true">
  <listeners>
    <add
      name="textWriterTraceListener"
      type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
      initializeData="C:\temp\log4net.txt" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
```